# How to discern Mouse events in ListBox and its ScrollBar

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to know somehow if user clicked or moved mouse onto ListBox itself or its scrollbar, but for now i always get message like it happened on/over listbox.

Comment: You will need to override the ListBox control and handle this yourself... Not ideal but I don't think there is any other way! :'[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had you provided some context to your question, it would be easier to answer. I had to do a similar thing when implementing visual feedback on a drag and drop operation although I have no idea if that's what you're doing. As such, all I can do is tell you how I managed my problem.

Basically, I used the [`SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.verticalscrollbarwidth%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
...
if (mouseXPositionInListBox > dragSourceControl.ActualWidth - 
    SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidth - dragSourceControl.Padding.Right) 
    isScrolling = true;
...
```

It can also be used in XAML:

```
<Grid Width="{DynamicResource 
    {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}" />
```

If you're working with the other dimension, there is also a [`SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeight` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.horizontalscrollbarheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

---

UPDATE >>>

You can detect whether a (vertical) `ScrollBar` is visible by reading the value of the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty DependencyProperty`:

```
ScrollBarVisibility visibility = (ScrollBarVisibility)yourListbox.GetValue(
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibilityProperty);
```

You *may* also be interested in using the [`ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportwidth.aspx) and/or the [`ScrollViewer.ViewportHeight` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportheight%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which will tell you the actual size of the visible area within the `ScrollViewer`.

Comment: Yau are great wizard.

Comment: But what if there no scroll bar at the moment, what if list not full, then i need to handle event to drag?